# How do I get my Nexus repo to download a more recent artifact?

Tags: gradle, nexus

We have a Nexus repository on my local network that is managed by a different team and I use it as a local mirror of Maven-central .    My Gradle 1.7 build script is trying to download a set of "Selenium 2.35.0" artifacts from the Nexus server  (which is setup as a mirror in my .m2/settings.xml  file) but it times out and fails.  There are 2.33.0 artifacts on the server though.

Is there a command I can issue from the command line to trigger the Nexus server to cache the latest version of Selenium?   OR , is this something the Nexus admin has to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle doesn't work with .m2/settings.xml.
You need to define your Nexus in gradle script itself (using `repositories{}` closure).

Comment: Your right.  Gradle is actually bypassing the .m2 Maven settings.xml file is is downloading directly from Maven central.  So, it appears I just have a general download problem of some kind.  Might be network related.   In any case, I am still curious how nexus gets triggered to cache updated resources.

Comment: Gradle has its own cache (located in .gradle dir).
You need to configure Gradle to download from your Nexus repositories (using `repositories{}` closure)

Answer (score 0):

Nexus is a caching proxy. It won't download the newer version unless someone asks for the newer version.